Quotient topoi as quotient objects
In Lawvere's Open problems in topos theory; quotient topoi are treated as connected geometric morphisms of Grothendieck topoi.
Is there a good reference for where these come from? Is there any sense in which these can be made into a quotient object in either 1-categorical, Grothendieck topoi + geometric morphisms, or bicategorical, add on geometric transformations, ways?

Because connected geometric morphisms are always surjective, the two definitions of quotient topos that you mention are equivalent.

For a variant of the question, the answer is positive in a certain sense. Locally connected geometric morphisms are open and hence of descent type. Being of descent type is a possible interpretation of (stably) regular epi in 2-dimensional category theory.
Notice that in the spectrum of epimorphisms, stably regular epi is a very strong notion. Thus it could very well be the case that connected geometric morphism happen to be somewhere else in the spectrum.

Personally I think that what Lawvere had in mind is the following. Let $\mathcal{E}$ be a topos. Then there is very little hope that one can control the number of the possible faithful functors $f^*: \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{E}$, with $\mathcal{F}$ varying among all the possible topoi. Even the topos of sets has a proper class of quotients in this sense, because every topos of the form $G$-Set has a surjective point.
Hence, the only chance Lawvere had to make the question somewhat meaningful was to restrict the notion of quotient to a more controllable one, for example, one that forced $f^*$ to be full and faithful. This is exactly the notion of connected geometric morphism.
I do not think he made a very good choice, or at least, I do not think he provided an insightful motivation for such a choice. I am even skeptical to believe that such a question deserved the attention he thought it should deserve.

In Lawvere's statement of the problem, he mentions a duality between subtoposes (inclusions) and quotients (connected geometric morphisms). Subtoposes correspond to left exact monads on the topos, while quotients correspond to left exact comonads on the topos. This is discussed on the nlab here, for the idempotency you can use Proposition 3.4 here.
Phrased in a different way, a subtopos is a full subcategory that is closed under limits and has a left exact reflection, while a quotient is a full subcategory that is closed under colimits and finite limits.
There is also a link with epimorphisms, see Section 6.2 of "Quotient toposes of discrete dynamical systems" by Hora and Kamio.
As a first demonstration, suppose you have a monoid homomorphism $\phi: M \to N$. Then a right $N$-set is a set $X$ together with a monoid homomorphism $\alpha: N \to \mathrm{End}(X)^\mathrm{op}$. We can now construct a functor from the topos of $N$-sets to the topos of $M$-sets by sending $(X, \alpha)$ to $(X, \alpha\circ\phi)$. This functor preserves colimits and finite limits. If $\phi$ is an epimorphism, then $\alpha\circ \phi = \beta\circ\phi$ implies $\alpha=\beta$. So two different $N$-sets are sent to different $M$-sets, which is a first step to showing that the topos of $N$-sets is in this case a quotient of the topos of $M$-sets (see "Quotient toposes of discrete dynamical systems", Proposition 6.6).
This is all very algebraic, so I would say that "quotient" in "quotient topos" refers more to the kind of quotients in algebra (quotient groups, quotient rings) than to the kind of quotients in geometry (quotient topology, quotient singularities). For the latter kind of quotients, the "open surjections" that Ivan Di Liberti mentions are a closer counterpart.
